# CreateView not creating any object

Tags: django, django-views

This is my view:

```
class ObjectCreateView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'dashboard/add.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = ObjectCreateForm
```

and this is how the view is called:

```
<a href="{% url 'dashboard:add' request.resolver_match.kwargs.slug %}">
  new
</a>
```

And the urls.py:

```
    path('<slug:slug>/object/new', views.ObjectCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
```

"slug" belongs to another object that is a foreign key in my object "object".

Is using slug the problem here ?

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/), CreateViews are supposed to have `model` and `field`attributes, to indicate the model type object that is to be created.  Is there a reason you aren't doing it that way?  It looks like you're trying to use a FormView, not a CreateView.

Comment: The same code works without `<slug:slug>` by passing `'dashboard:add'` without any parameter. however, model and field are configured in the form.

Comment: if "form_class" is specified then I can do this in the form class.

Comment: You haven't said what "the problem" is. What is the slug for? Where are you using it? What happens when you use this code, and what error do you get?